# How to Close SPModalDialog & Refresh page from Code behind in SandBox solution?

Tags: sandbox-solution, modal-dialog

I have Submit button in my SPModalPopup.

By clicking submit button, after executing some code, I want to close the ModalDialog & Refresh the parent page. How can I do this ?

I have tried different following methods individually, but none of them is working.

1) this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(.......);

2) HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); (This always give me NullReferenceException)

3) HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("window.opener='self';window.close();");

Also, in JavaScript file, I have written,

options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(                          null, modalDialogClosedCallback);

and its modalDialogClosedCallback method, but still its not working.

Please help me to close this & refresh page from server side.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this...

```
options.dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult) 
{ 
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult) 
}
```

The page gets refeshed, when the Dialog is closed with "OK"